# How do I initialize a result variable?

Tags: java

I need to make the result variable so that it is concatenated with my other strings to print my result and I tried multiple ways that are not working.

I have included my set of strings and first if statement to give an idea of my project.

My project rubric states "Initialize 'result' as a single string using concatenation. This string will contain the event type, party size, as as meal and preparation suggestions. Prints the result variable to the console." It also says " 'result' is a string that will be printed to the console.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class whatToEat {   

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int partySize;
        String eventType;

        System.out.println("Is your event Casual, Semi-Formal, or Formal?");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        eventType = sc.next();

        System.out.println("How many people will your event have?");
        partySize = sc.nextInt();

        if (eventType.equals("Casual") && partySize == 1) {

            System.out.println("Since you're hosting a casual event for "
                    + partySize + 
                    " person, you should serve sandwiches prepared in the mircowave. ");
```

Comment: My project rubric states "Initialize 'result' as a single string using concatenation. This string will contain the event type, party size, as as meal and preparation suggestions. Prints the result variable to the console." It also says " 'result' is a string that will be printed to the console"

Comment: You are already concatenating strings to print them using `println`. All you need to do is assign that to `String result`. Then you can call `System.out.println(result)`.

Answer (score 0):

Because it says that 'result' is a string that you print in console, I suggest you saving your information in a String first:

`String result = "";`

Then:

`result = "Since you're hosting a casual event for "
+ partySize + 
" person, you should serve sandwiches prepared in the mircowave."`

Finally:

`System.out.println(result);`

Comment: So if I change my string to result. What do I do with the eventType so that it is a variable in my program?